# Optimisation of the export function

Tags: mysql, cakephp, optimization

I am wondering what would be the best way to speed up the company export function in my application:

```
function export(){
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

    $conditions = $this->getConditions($this->data);
    $resultCompanies = $this->Company->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));

    $this->set(compact('resultCompanies'));
}
```

So what it does is it searches for the companies in the databse that match certain conditions. Then the results are set to be able to be displayed in the corresponding view.

How can I speed this function up? The more results you want to export the more time it takes to export them but is it possible to optimize it in some way? It currently takes around 30 seconds to export just 4000 results - so I don't imagine it being able to export say 40000 results and it should be able to? Is it a matter of the server?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try the same thing without using compact?

Comment: Why using a view for so many records? Export it it a file (csv) for example. Can even be done via CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a matter of the server but of the program architecture.

You do not want to fetch and render this huge amount of information on the fly for obvious reasons you already have encountered.

I don't know enough about the requirements of your app but I assume that you need to download a report. **Assuming it has to be always up to date** here is what I would do:

The user clicks the link to download the report. The user will get a loading indicator displayed and a message that is report export is being prepared using JS and AJAX. On the server side a task is triggered to build a report.

A background service, a simple CakePHP shell that runs in a loop, will notice that there is a new report to build. It will build the report **reading the db records in chunks to avoid running out of memory** and write it to a file. When it's done the report download request is flagged as done and the file can be downloaded. On the client side the long polling JS script notices that the file is ready and downloads it.

**Another solution, assuming the data does not has to be up to date**, would be to generate the report files one time per day for example and have them available for download without any waiting time for the user. On the server side the task will stay the same: Read and write the data in chunks.

**About the performance part of the question:**

It this does not make it faster but it gives the user a feedback, you could even calculate (estimate) the remaining time based on the already processed chunks and further it prevents the script from crashing because of running out of memory. **Instead of writing the file to disk you could directly stream it to the client**. As soon as it starts reading the first chunk you'll start sending the data. But reading the data from the database... Well throw money and hardware on it. I suggest you something like a RAID5 array with SSDs if you have the money. Expect to throw a few thousand dollar on it.

But even the fastest DB read is limited by the bandwidth you can send and the user can receive. For speeding up the DB I recommend you to ask on superuser.com, I'm not an expert for DB hardware but a properly set up SSD configuration gives a huge speed boost to your DB.

**Fetch only data you need:**

I don't see any contain() or recursive setting in your find: Make sure you only fetch data that is really needed in the report!

Comment: Hi. The export cannot be made in advance because each user may specify his own conditions for the export. I dont get what in your javascript/ajax solution makes it faster than in my solution with the export I presented above?

Comment: The function does stream the results directly to the user. It is getting the data from the database because different conditions may apply for a different sql query.

Comment: Well, instead of let people guessing and writing a novel please mention all of that the next time in your question... Thank you. The only solution to speed it up then is to throw hardware and money on it. But even the fastest DB read is limited by the bandwidth you can send and the user can receive. For speeding up the DB I recommend you to ask on superuser.com, I'm not an expert for DB hardware but a  properly set up SSD configuration gives a huge speed boost to your DB.